# C++ Return is different if a Printf is in a function

Tags: c++, printf

I am experiencing a rather strange thing. I am currently working on a function that calculates the shape factor of a shape. The perimeter and area functions work perfectly fine however I have discovered something.

The code that out puts the right answer

```
double Shapefactor (char line [50][50]){

double sfactor;
double perimeter1= (Perimeter(line));
printf("peri = %f", perimeter1);
double area1=((double)Area(line));
sfactor = ((perimeter1 * perimeter1) /area1);                           
printf("----------------------------------------------------*Therefore the shape factor for the given shape is* %f \n", sfactor);  

   return (sfactor);                                              
 }
```

This provides me the correct output. However if I was to remove this line from the code

```
printf("peri = %f", perimeter1);
```

Then it gives me the wrong number. Do you have any idea why this is?

Area code

```
int Area (char line [50][50]){
int x;                                                       
int y;
int sum;                                                       

  for (x = 0; x <= 50; x++) {                                
    for (y = 0; y <= 50; y++) {                              


      if (line[x][y] == '1')                                 
        sum++;                                           

    }
  }



 return (sum);                                                  

 }
```

Perimeter

```
int Perimeter (char line [50][50]){
int x;                                                      
int y;
int sumup;                                                       
FILE * f_ptr;
char filename[20];


  for (x = 0; x < 50; x++) {
    for (y = 0; y < 50; y++) {

      if (line[x][y + 1] == '0' & line[x][y] == '1')         
        sumup++;                                                    
      else if (line[x][y] == '1' & line[x][y - 1] == '0')  
        sumup++;                                                   
      else if (line[x + 1][y] == '0' & line[x][y] == '1')    
        sumup++;                                                  
      else if (line[x][y] == '1' & line[x - 1][y] == '0')   
        sumup++;                                                   

    }
  }

 return (sumup);                                                    

  }
```

Thank you

Comment: Please provide a [mcve]. We can’t see from this what the functions do or anything. Most likely you’re doing something that causes undefined behavior.

Comment: please provide code for Perimeter and Area.

Comment: This is usually a symptom of undefined behavior somewhere in the program. It might not be in this function, it could be anything that happened earlier.

Comment: BTW, why are you using `printf()` in C++ instead of `std::cout`?

Comment: In this example providing code from the functions of Area and Perimeter are not appropriate. This is because the issue is that removing the printf line causes the output to be wrong.

Comment: Why are you not using `std::vector` and `std::string`? Guess in the past you wrote C.

Comment: No idea whether it's related, but the loop in Area uses out-of-bound indices. Indices in `char line [50][50]` are 0 to 49, you use 0 to 50. That is undefined behavior and may break things in unpredictable ways (or predictable, you just read more values than you want). And that's one reason why the rest of the code is important.

Comment: Help us help you. Provide working code and tell use what the expected answer is and what the wrong answer is. Also with floating point numbers, small differences don't necessarily mean wrong

Comment: @Frax Just realised that, Changed it to 49 however is still throwing the same issue. The perimeter is 130 and the area is 1012. The expected shapefactor is 16.699605 however when I remove the printf it provides 14.798599

Comment: You need to initialize `sumup` and `sum`

Comment: You shouldn't change to 49, you should change it to `< 50`, which is idiomatic (and you even have it in other function).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The variable `sum` in `Area()` (EDIT: and also `sumup` in `Perimeter()`, as noted by @agbinfo) is uninitialized:

```
int Area (char line [50][50]){
//...
int sum;                                                       

  for (x = 0; x <= 50; x++) {
    for (y = 0; y <= 50; y++) {
      if (line[x][y] == '1')
        sum++;
//...
```

This is undefined behavior; this being an automatic variable, it's likely what you're reading there is garbage left on the stack by a previous function call, i.e. whether you invoke `printf()` or not makes the difference you're seeing.

I recommend enabling compiler warnings and linters which would usually catch these sort of errors.

Comment: Exactly that, enable compiler warnings and half of stupid problems just go away.

Comment: @Vacation: unrelated to your original issue, but: `Perimeter()` is using a bitwise and (`&`) to do what a boolean and (`&&`) should do -- in its current form the parsing is ambiguous, e.g. compiler doesn't know whether you mean `if ((x == 0) & (y == 1))` or `if (x == (0 & (y == 1)))`.